# Mongodb time difference check

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here's my data in a mongodb document

```
[
    {
        startTime: "08:00",
        endTime: "09:00",
        id: 1
    },
    {
        startTime: "08:10",
        endTime: "09:00",
        id: 2
    },
    {
        startTime: "10:00",
        endTime: "11:00",
        id: 3
    }
]
```

I need to find a way to get time overlapping elements using mongoose with node.js
I trid using $dateFromString but no luck so far.
for example item id 1 and 2 has time overlap

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if trying to find elements by time, consider using a datetime datatype rather than string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { startTime: 1 },
      output: {
        previous_endTime: {
          $shift: {
            output: "$endTime",
            by: -1,
            default: "Not available"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      c: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $and: [
              { $gte: [ "$previous_endTime", "$endTime" ] },
              { $gte: [ "$previous_endTime", "$startTime" ] }
            ]
          },
          then: 0,
          else: 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "",
      sortBy: { startTime: 1 },
      output: {
        c: {
          $sum: "$c",
          window: { documents: [ "unbounded", "current" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$c",
      c: { $sum: 1 },
      id_List: { $push: "$id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { c: { $gt: 1 } }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O-8NQX0vUn1)